# Unable to log-in to Phpmyadmin using Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using Ubuntu 14.4 and installed phpmyadmin. When prompt to log in the root user and my user does not log-in. I tried reinstalling and to no surprise this didn't help.  There is no error that shows up.

Comment: how you did installed & configured.

Comment: I used the terminal to download and followed the standard installation, selected apache2, unix, and then it went to password/naming db section. I added the include in the apache.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Can you able to access mysql from command line. If no, you can reset your mysql root password, by using the below command.

```
service mysql stop
echo "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('mypassword') WHERE User = 'root';" > ~/mysql-reset.sql 
echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" >> ~/mysql-reset.sql 
sudo chown mysql:mysql ~/mysql-reset.sql 
mysqld_safe --init-file=~/mysql-reset.sql & rm ~/mysql-reset.sql # confirm it works 
mysql --user=root --password=mypassword > quit; 
service mysql stop 
service mysql start
```